# Group by pandas data frame unique first values - numpy array returned

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, unique

From a two string columns pandas data frame looking like:

```
d = {'SCHOOL' : ['Yale', 'Yale', 'LBS', 'Harvard','UCLA', 'Harvard', 'HEC'],
     'NAME' : ['John', 'Marc', 'Alex', 'Will', 'Will','Miller', 'Tom']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Notice the relationship between NAME to SCHOOL is n to 1. 
I want to get the last school in case one person has gone to two different schools (see "Will" case).

So far I got:

```
df = df.groupby('NAME')['SCHOOL'].unique().reset_index()
```

Return:

```
     NAME           SCHOOL
0    Alex            [LBS]
1    John           [Yale]
2    Marc           [Yale]
3  Miller        [Harvard]
4     Tom            [HEC]
5    Will  [Harvard, UCLA]
```

PROBLEMS:

- unique() return both school not only the **last school**.
- This line return SCHOOL column as a **np.array instead of string**. Very difficult to work further with this df.

Comment: Try `last` instead of `unique`.

Comment: Thanks @IanS! This works to get rid off the np.array for all the Schools but for the Will's ones. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: My fault... I didn't re-defined `df` variable. `last()` works perfectly. Thanks man!! I'm new at python, if you don't mind could you explain why `last()` worked? (Pandas documentation didn't help me much...)

Comment: `last` is one of the aggregation functions available after a groupby, and clearly the one you were looking for. See for instance [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) for general thoughts on aggregation. Or see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id32) for a full list of aggregation functions available on a groupby object.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will answer the question with your comment then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both problems where solved based on @IanS comments.

Using `last()` instead of `unique()`:

```
df = df.groupby('NAME')['SCHOOL'].last().reset_index()
```

Return:

```
     NAME   SCHOOL
0    Alex      LBS
1    John     Yale
2    Marc     Yale
3  Miller  Harvard
4     Tom      HEC
5    Will     UCLA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `last` and specifying column for check duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('NAME', keep='last')
print (df)
     NAME   SCHOOL
0    John     Yale
1    Marc     Yale
2    Alex      LBS
4    Will     UCLA
5  Miller  Harvard
6     Tom      HEC
```

Also if need sorting add [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('NAME', keep='last').sort_values('NAME')
print (df)
     NAME   SCHOOL
2    Alex      LBS
0    John     Yale
1    Marc     Yale
5  Miller  Harvard
6     Tom      HEC
4    Will     UCLA
```